# SQL Alchemy the data types text and text are incompatible in the equal operator

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, python-2.x

In part of my django API I have the following, to update old notes:

```
old_note = request.databaseSession.query(Tmemo).\
    filter(Tmemo.memosern1 == serial).\
    one()
```

This query works without any problem as I am using it many other places. The weird problem comes with:

```
old_note.memotext = newtext
```

Then when I commit the following errors happens:

```
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', u'[42000] 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The data types 
text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) 
(SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: u'UPDATE tmemo SET memotext=? WHERE 
tmemo.memosern1 = ? AND tmemo.memosern2 = ? AND tmemo.memotype = ? AND 
tmemo.memotext = ?'] [parameters: ('asassasasasaassaassaasas2121', 
u'P03000000060445', u'MEMO', u'5', u'asassasasasaassaassaasas')] 
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Tmemo is just a table with column for a serial number `memosern1` and `memosern2`, type with `memotype` and the notes itself as `memotext`, serials and type are varchar and memotext as text. I really don't understand what `text and text are incompatible` means really, it makes no sense, also I am just filtering the serial number, nothing else, so what is up with this weird query?

And I can perfectly create another row in the table with the exact same variables being used (`newtext`), I just can't update an existent one.

Any ideias? I can provide more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TEXT`-type is really just a `BLOB` and can be very large, depending on your database server 2**64-1 bytes or even more. Because of its (possible) size, the equality operator is not implemented for `TEXT` and `BLOB`, therefore you can't compare values of type `TEXT` to anything (in your case `TEXT to TEXT`).

What you have to do is either use a `VARCHAR` or - alternatively, slightly hacky - compute and store the hash of the `TEXT`-column and compare that instead. If you compute the `MD5()` of the `TEXT`-value, store only the upper 64bit as an `INT` and put a functional index on that column, you can basically have the same result without too much cost (except the extra hash + index operation on insert/update and a very slight chance that you compare something to equality that is not really equal).

In the long term, you should use `VARCHAR` instead of `TEXT`, as `TEXT` will be [removed from future versions of SQL Server.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)